# Can't activate CORS in serveless with only default endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a serverless file with only the default endpoint and I'm deploying in AWS.
Everything seems to work fine when I make the petition to postman, but when I try to implement this endpoint to my frontend in Vue (localhost) I get the following error:
"has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."
I have already tried to activate the CORS options in AWS but it doesn't,t work.
Thanks for your time and help

```
functions:
  connect-api:
    handler: api.handler
    name: something
    description: Connect api
    timeout: 29
    events:
      - httpApi: '*'
      - http:
          path: /{any+} 
          method: ANY
```

Comment: try  events:
     - http:
         method: any
         cors: true
         path: /{any+}

Comment: with the httpApi: '*' or do I substitute it for any path?

Comment: events:
     - http:
         method: any
         cors: true
         path: /{any+}